# Units of expected value and moments of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, average

Might be a straightforward question, but I've been getting some mixed answers and I'd like to know for sure if my understanding is correct. Suppose I've some random variable $X$ and the expected value of this random variable is to be used in an equation. For example, let $X$ be the amount of apples per person, and I'm interested in calculating the amount of apples eaten by a group of people over time. A differential equation for the amount of apples in the population, $A$, may look something like this:

$$\dot{A} = - \alpha A \sum_x xp(x),$$ where each individual in the population has probability $p(x)$ of possessing $x$ apples, and $\alpha$ is the apple-eating rate. The sum is just the expected value of the number of apples in the population, and we let this be denoted by $\mu$, so our differential equation becomes $$\dot{A} = -\alpha \mu A$$ but now the units don't quite work out, as $[\alpha] = [1/time]$ and $[A] = [apples]$. Is $\mu$ unitless or am I formulating the equation incorrectly? I've even seen instances where the mean is dependent on a state variable, e.g. $\mu = N/A$ for some other state variable $N$, which would make the above differential equation $$\dot{A} = -\alpha A \left(\frac{N}{A}\right) = -\alpha N,$$ which can be a bit confusing dimension-wise, especially when $N$ has nothing to do with apples! This question applies to higher moments as well, e.g. problems of the form $$\dot{A} = -\alpha A \sum_x x^2 p(x) = -\alpha A E(X^2).$$

Comment: $A \sum\limits_x xp(x)$ looks as if it has units of apples squared (or square apples?) so if $\alpha$ has units of $1/$time then your original equation may have unit issues

Comment: @Henry So the formulation as it stands is incorrect, even though it is mathematically sound?

Comment: @DerekAdams: it seems like the model is misspecified. For instance, if $X$ is the number of apples per person, then $\sum_x xp(x)$ is the average number of apples per person (not per group). Then "The sum is just the expected value of the number of apples in the population" is invalid. Most importantly, it makes sense to say that the change in apples per unit time is proportional to the number of apples (e.g. eat more before they spoil). But why multiply by the mean of $X$? I see no possible reasong for that.

Comment: @PontusHultkrantz I see, so the multiplication by $X$ is unneeded. The correct form would be something like $A = -\alpha \sum_x xp(x)$, where $\alpha$ is the apple-eating-rate per person.

Comment: When in doubt, remember that $1 = \int dx \ p(x)$, thus $[p(x)] = 1/[x]$. Probability densities have units, probability masses are dimensionless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean has the same units as the random variable, period. Then, for a dimensionally consistent equation, you should have $[\alpha]=([X][{\rm time}])^{-1}$

The same goes for the units of the moments, i.e. $[ E(X^k)] = [X]^k$